# Brother HL-1210W Debian 11 / Linux & A6 support

Tags: debian, cups, printer

I want to use a Brother HL-1210W on Debian 11 (Bullseye). I added it as wireless printer without drivers but it didnt work. Also the paper size A6 is not listed in its supported sizes.

How can I make the printer work? Will it print on A6 paper?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great cheap compact laser printer, so i hoped it would work,

I found out there is a driver installed on the brother website for this
https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=au&lang=en&prod=hl1210w_eu_as&os=128

The installer didnt work right away it seemed to be missing some things, so i had to install: (the first few were prompted, others were errored)

libc6-i386, lib32gcc-s1, lib32stdc++6, lpr, lib32z1

As for A6 support, editing the CUPS file didnt work, but it turns out, so long as you are printing in the upper half of an A4 page you can just feed the printer an a6 sheet and it works fine.